# Django how to create a dynamic field

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I don’t understand the principle of a dynamic field.

In my case I have 3 classes on my models:
1- Product : name, ref, description and availability (availability should not be coded in the database and be define dynamicly. It should return available or out of stock).
2- Location : name of the location.
3- Stock : foreign key for Product and foreign key for Location and number a product(INT).

The idea is : if in Stock there is 1 or more of a product, the products endpoint shows available. If 0 it shows out of stock.

Is that even possible?

EDIT:
Here the code for Models.py

```
from django.db import models


class Product(models.Model):

    product_reference = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True, blank=True)
    reference_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True, blank=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=500, unique=True, blank=True)
    """availability = available or out of stock // should not be coded in the database"""


class Location(models.Model):

    location_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True, blank=True)


class Stock(models.Model):

    reference = models.ForeignKey(
        "app.Product", blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    bar = models.ForeignKey("app.Location", blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    stock = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
```

Comment: Can you share your models

Answer (score 0):

I think there are several options, how you could implement this.

You could not persist the availability attribute inside the Product Model. Instead, when the desired template is rendered, you could use a template filter to check if there are any Products in Stock and then just show a different message in the HTML Template.

May something like that:

```
# product_list.html
{% comment %} Load the custom filters (should be named like the python file below) {% endcomment %}
{% load custom_filters %}
{% for product in products %}
    <p>{{ product.name }} {{ product.id|check_availability }}</p>
{% endfor %}

# custom_filters.py
# This file have to be placed inside a folder named 'templatetags' which has to be created inside the root directory of your app
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def check_availability(value)
    products_in_stock = Stock.objects.get(product_id=value.id).values('number')
    if products_in_stock > 0:
        return 'Available'
    else:
        return 'Out of Stock'
```

For further explanation, how to implement your own template tags and filters, check out the [Django Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/howto/custom-template-tags/) on it.

You could also use [Django Signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/signals/) to check after each update or creation of a Stock object, if the quantity of a product is below 1 and afterwards update the availability field in the Product Model accordingly. For example if you create the field as a CharField(), you could set the value of the Product inside the Signal to 'Out of Stock' or 'Available'.

I think I would implement it with an own template filter (as I have described firstly).

Comment: Thanks, thats the idea, but I don't use HTML everything stays in the API endpoints.